# '(value as List).isNotEmpty': 'array-contains-any' filters require a non-empty [List]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

here I am getting all the following ids and storing in list of string

```
  List<String> followinguserid = [];
  Future<QuerySnapshot> _timelinepoststream;
  getAllFollowingId() async {
    String currentuserid = await UserSecureStorage.getUserId();
    print(currentuserid);
    await followingRef
        .doc(currentuserid)
        .collection('userFollowing')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        followinguserid.add(element.id);
      });
    });
 
  }
```

in init function i am making the query

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getAllFollowingId();
    _timelinepoststream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .where('UserIds', arrayContainsAny: [
     ...followinguserid
    ]).get();
  }
```

here i am using future builder and passing the future

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var height = SizeConfig.getHeight(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _timelinepoststream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            print(snapshot.data.docs);
            documents = snapshot.data.docs;
            return Text("sample");
            }})}
```

I am getting this error
[image: emulator screenshot error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getAllFollowingId` is an `async` method, you need to use `await` when calling it:

```
await getAllFollowingId();
```

Without `await` your database query runs before the `followinguserid` has been populated, which explains the error message.

---

If you can't use `await`, you can also use a `then()` callback:

```
getAllFollowingId().then(() {
  _timelinepoststream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .where('UserIds', arrayContainsAny: [
   ...followinguserid
  ]).get();
})
```

Comment: getAllFollowingId().then(() {
      _timelinepoststream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .where('UserIds', arrayContainsAny: [...followinguserid]).get();
    });

error : nother exception was thrown: type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'